# Issue with scanf() function in c?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()  
 {  
  int i;  
   char a[20];   
   char b[20];   
   scanf("%d",&i);  
    gets(a);   
    puts(a);  
gets(b);  
puts(b);
```

}

Here,after entering the value of 'a' it is printing the value of i and a.It is not taking the value of 'b'.How i can insert the value of 'b'?

Comment: Mandatory notice: _never_ use `gets`. It has been removed from the C standard since it is impossible to use safely.

Comment: also, don't use `scanf()` either – it's hard to use correctly, and almost naturally, you got it wrong. Use `fgets()` to read in an entire line, and parse/convert it to the appropriate data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Never use `gets`, it has been removed from the C standard, and is unsafe. Use `fgets` instead, (e.g., `fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin);`). Note that `fgets` doesn't remove the newline from the end of the string.

2) The return type of `main` is `int`, not `void`.

3) The `scanf` does not consume the newline after reading `i`, so `gets(a)` results in `a` being the empty string because it reads the newline that was buffered from when the user pressed return after typing the number. Then `gets(b)` reads what you thought was `a`. (Print some prompts before reading each value and you'll see. Or try the input: <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Suggested solution: use `fgets` to read `i` into a buffer, then, e.g., `atoi` or `strtol` to convert it to an integer. (Or you could do an extra `fgets` after `scanf`, or `getchar` in a loop until you've read a newline, but, seriously, the `fgets` solution is a lot more robust and worth learning now.)

Comment: "Suggested solution: use `fgets` to read `i` into a buffer" – **YES!** Exactly, that's how it should be done. `scanf()` is stupid (as in it's hard to use correctly and is unreasonably, disproportionately rarely useful.)

Answer (score 0):

```
  gets(a);
```

Don't use `gets` it is evil. Try `fgets`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()   //declare here `int main()`
 {  
     int i;  
     char a[20],c[10];   
     char b[20];   
     fgets(c,sizeof c,stdin);
     i=atoi(c);         
     fgets(a,sizeof a,stdin);   
     puts(a);  
     fgets(b,sizeof b,stdin);  
     puts(b); 
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the `sizeof` edit. =) A couple of issues remain: `c` should be `int` (as the value `EOF` is distinct from any `char`), and the switch to `fgets` causes the newlines to remain in `a` and `b`, which shows up as extra newlines in the output.

Comment: @Arkku  Yes you are very correct .Sorry for my foolishness .